# how to use a global variable to create turtle inside a population that has already been created using another global variable

Tags: netlogo

Create a number of infected turtles in each population (brown and magenta) determined by the global variable initially_infected. For example if initially_infected is set to 10 there would be 10 individuals in the brown population infected and 10 individuals in the magenta population infected.

```
to initialise_agents

  create-turtles magenta_population[
   set color yellow
   set size 1
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = magenta]]

  create-turtles brown_population[
      set color yellow
      set size 1
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = brown]
  ]
```

now I need to change color of 10 turtles in both the magenta and brown population, but it shpuld be determined by the global variable initially_infected

I am new to netlogo. Unfortunately,  I got an assignment from my university. the question is:
In this project you will be developing a model to ascertain important factors the impact the spread of an infectious disease among a population of agents within a particular timeframe. You will have 2 populations of agents that are infected with a virus which will spread among the populations. You will analyse factors that impact the spread and mortality rate such as population density, social distancing, self-isolation and the amount of time the virus can go undetected whist transmissible.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an assignment, I prefer not giving full answers (how else are you supposed to learn).
But you might want to take a look at the [`n-of`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-of) primitive

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it have to be determined by the global variable initially_infected

Comment: @MuhammedBasil yes, `n-of` is the primitive that you can use to select a certain number of turtles. It's exactly what you need to change the color of `initially_infected` number of turtles.